# how to refer to local and upper level LHS

Tags: r, pipe

In the following, is there a way to refer to both `expr1` and `expr2` in the `expr`?

```
expr1 %>% {
  expr2 %>% expr
}
```

For example, this doesn’t work

```
mtcars %>% {
  mtcars[1:3] %>% mutate(disp2 = disp + hp)
}
```

Another example, is there a way to make the output to be `32 11 32 3`, i.e. make the first `.` refer to the upper level LHS?

```
mtcars %>% {
  mtcars[1:3] %>% {cat(dim(.),dim(.))}
}
```

Just curious!

Thanks,

update -----------

Thank you for the comments and suggestion, @GregorThomas and @Victor! My intention isn't specifically regarding those two examples, but how to write code w/o breaking the piping, e.g. I don't want to write this to use `x` for the upper level LHS in `expr`

```
expr1 %>% {
  x <- .
  expr2 %>% expr 
}
```

Comment: You could use anonymous functions with named arguments so the scoping is clearer. But I think the readability will be abysmal in either case. I have no idea what your intent is in the first example.

Comment: As @GregorThomas said, you can use `mtcars %>% (function(upper) {mtcars[1:3] %>% mutate(disp2 = disp + upper$hp)})` and equivalently `mtcars %>% (function(upper) {mtcars[1:3] %>% {cat(dim(upper),dim(.))}})`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% {
  mtcars[1:3] %>% {cat(dim(parent.env(environment())$.), dim(.))}
}
```

This will print `32 11 32 3`

`environment()` returns the current environment and `parent.env` the environment one level up in the call stack, which you can then access using the dollar operator to get the value of dot.

To make your first example work, use the [bang-bang](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting) operator to force early evaluation:

```
library(rlang)

mtcars %>% {
  mtcars[1:3] %>% mutate(disp2 = disp + !!parent.env(environment())$.$hp)
}
```

---

I found it helpful to take a look at the call stack, which can be done by running

```
mtcars %>% {
  mtcars[1:3] %>% {lobstr::cst()}
}
```

output:

```
    ▆
 1. ├─mtcars %>% ...
 2. ├─mtcars[1:3] %>% ...
 3. └─lobstr::cst()
```